# How to change Laravel's language with Vuejs for get errors from validator?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

Can someone explain to me how to succeed to dynamically change Laravel's language with Vuejs?

I use [Nuxt.js](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/) with [nuxt-i18n](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/setup.html).

I have 2 .json files (fr_FR and en_US). The translation works well.

But for my forms, I'm get the errors that Laravel sends me back thanks to [vform](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform).

When I change the language, for example from French to English, the errors remain in French.

I would like them to be in English too.

I know I have to change the locale in Laravel too, but I do not know how to do it with Vuejs.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add language header to your API calls.
You can do it by:

1. Configuring axios https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults as `vform` uses `axios` as http handler
2. Setting `config` in every form call via `vform` https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/src/Form.js#L106

`this.form.post('/login', config)`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it without Nuxt, the process should be similar.

You'll need to install `martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator` and `vuex-i18n`, then generate the translation files with the package's artisan command. When generated, import and use `import vuexI18n from 'vuex-i18n'`
 `Vue.use(vuexI18n.plugin, store)`, import generated file `import Locales from './vue-i18n-locales.generated.js`, add the desired locale(s) `Vue.i18n.add('ar', Locales.ar)`, set the locale `Vue.i18n.set(this.locale)` and use translated strings `{{ $t('home.home_text') }}`